# How can I find out which lines my regex matched on?

Tags: python, regex

I have a multiline string and want to apply a regular expression to it in Python. Is there a way to find out which line(s) a regex matched on?

For example, if I used the regex

```
regex = re.compile("(?<=i)s")
```

on the string

```
s = """This
is
a multiline
string"""
```

how could I find out that lines `0` and `1` matched? `regex.findall(s)` gives me a list of all matches, but it doesn't tell me which line these matches are on.

Comment: Are you reading a file? If so, how are you reading it?

Comment: It's just a multiple-line string (nothing that needs/involves files).

Comment: @ammt, do you consider cases when a match spans multiple lines?

Comment: @perreal: No, I don't, and a need to return matching lines might not make much sense in that case anyway (at least because the string would be treated as one line).

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, Thank you for your help. Your remake gave me a useful template.

Comment: You've provided quite a few great approaches and the thread now looks like a great reference, so I'm considering (for the sake of completeness) adding a related question (finding out the position within the whole string of [the first character of] each match). Do you think we should use this thread, or should it be a separate question?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `regex.finditer` you could get the line number like this:

```
regex = re.compile("(?<=i)s")
s = """This
is
a multiline
string"""
for match in regex.finditer(s):
    lineno = s.count('\n', 0, match.start())
    ...
```

Comment: This has the advantage of handling regex matches that span a line break, but it also does a lot of counting the same newlines again and again for each match.

Comment: on the other hand it uses just one regex operation... can't say which would be faster. maybe i'll try to timeit

Comment: You could also remember the last starting position and number of newlines thus far, avoiding to count the earlier newlines twice. Also, this regex will find multiple matches on the same line and thus possibly add the same line number to the result list multiple times. That may be a good feature - or a distraction, depending on what @ammt really needs. Perhaps he could edit the question to specify the desired behavior.

Comment: Yea, that would improve it a little - i tried that and timed it [here](http://pastebin.com/yjWDsFqi) (not much difference). I'll leave the simpler version here because it's a little clearer what it's doing. I think if the regex matches multiple times on the line, also the solution should...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enumerate()` to get the line numbers:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("(?<=i)s")
>>> results = []
>>> for lineno, line in enumerate(s.split("\n")):
...     if regex.search(line):
...         results.append((lineno, line))
...
>>> results
[(0, 'This'), (1, 'is')]
```

Of course, if you don't need the line's contents themselves, just do `results.append(lineno)`.

Answer (score 3):

One simple method would be alternate matching newlines:

```
lineno=1
for m in re.findall(r'\n|(?<=i)s', s):
    if m != '\n': print lineno, m
    else : lineno += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `re.MULTILINE`, a caret (`^`) matches at the beginning of a string and at the beginning of a line. Changing your regex slightly, will give you a list of all lines, with an empty string where you didn't match:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("(^.*(?<=i)s|^)", re.MULTILINE)
>>> regex.findall(s)
['This', 'is', '', '']
```

The line numbers are then the index plus one of the list where the string is not empty:

```
>>> [(i + 1, j) for (i, j) in enumerate(regex.findall(s)) if j != '']
[(1, 'This'), (2, 'is')]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second question you asked in the comment,

you can do either with `re` and `StringIO`

```
import re
from StringIO import StringIO

s = """This
is
a multiline
string.
This is a line with several "is\""""

print s

rgx = re.compile("(?<=i)s")

def graou(s):
    sl = 0
    for i,line in enumerate(StringIO(s)):
        tu = tuple(sl+m.start() for m in rgx.finditer(line))
        if tu: yield (i,tu)
        sl += len(line)

print [x for x in graou(s) if x[1]]
```

either with `re` only (I prefer):

```
import re

s = """This
is
a multiline
string.
This is a line with several "is\""""

print s

rgx = re.compile('$|(?<=i)s',re.MULTILINE)

def graou(s):
    i,li = 0,[]
    for m in rgx.finditer(s):
        if m.group()!='':
            li.append(m.start())
        elif li:
            yield((i,tuple(li)))
            i += 1
            li = []
```